# Formal name of vector identity

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

I just derived this simple vector identity
$$\mathbf{a}\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}\times\left(\mathbf{b} \times\mathbf{c}\right)\right) = \left(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}\right).$$

This can be done fairly easily:

Application of the vector triple product identity to the left hand side gives $$\mathbf{a}\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}\times\left(\mathbf{b} \times\mathbf{c}\right)\right) = \mathbf{a}\cdot\left((\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b}-(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b})\mathbf{c}\right) =\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b} -\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b})\mathbf{c}.$$
Application of the scalar quadruple product identity to the right hand side gives $$\left(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{b}\times\mathbf{c}\right) =  (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})-(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b}).$$

From this, it directly follows that \begin{align}
\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c})\mathbf{b} &\stackrel{!}{=} (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{c}) \text{ and}\\
\mathbf{a}\cdot(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b})\mathbf{c} &\stackrel{!}{=} (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{b}),
\end{align}
which is obviously a true statement.

I am currently writing a paper and would like to cite the formal name of this identity, but was unfortunately not able to find it anywhere online thus far. Does anybody have a clue what it is called in literature?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The fact that $\left(\mathbf{a}\times\mathbf{b}\right)\cdot\left(\mathbf{c}\times\mathbf{d}\right) =  (\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{b})(\mathbf{c}\cdot\mathbf{d})-(\mathbf{a}\cdot\mathbf{c})(\mathbf{b}\cdot\mathbf{d})$ is sometimes called the [Binet-Cauchy identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity); an application of this amounts to a half of what you have proved.

Even on [this page of identities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_algebra_relations#Addition_and_multiplication_of_vectors), I didn't see anything like your expression on the left. I don't know what to call it since you've already used the term "scalar quadruple product".

Perhaps a good name for your identity would be a "scalar quadruple product identity" in the sense that it says that two such products are equal.